# What is the best way to update your status on a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, best-practices

When progress is made after asking a question I have been editing my original post and adding progress at the bottom. Is this the best practice or is there a better way? Would comments be better?

-Thanks

Comment: Thanks, your answers were helpful ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're adding more information about the problem, just update the original post.  If you're providing a solution, make it an answer.  If someone else leaves a comment asking for clarification, respond in a comment and update the post with the new information.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like to see edits like you describe.

**Update 1**
I still like to see them like this.

**Update 2**
Yep, I dig it!

Answer (score 1):

You can see one example of how I do it, here:

[Windows Server 2008 R2 network adapter stops working, requires hard reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/104791/what-does-it-mean-when-arp-shows-incomplete-on-eth1)

This one is really a bitch.